# Is it possible to connect your phone to the computer and use the PCs' headset?

Tags: usb

I've got a splendid headset for my computer and I want to use it with my phone. The connection between headset and the PC is via USB 2.0. I wonder if it is possible to connect your phone to the computer and use the PCs' headset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect via Bluetooth and play music from the phone and make calls. By USB un can only use Computer Internet Connection.

Edit: Sorry I think I misunderstood what you whant. Since you can connect Windows Phone in PC via bluetooth I think you can use PC headset instead of PC speacker.

Comment: @BennySkogberg Good to hear that. If it really solve the puzzle please remember to mark as answer. ;)

Comment: Count on it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that isn't going to work. The audio is only delivered over the headphone jack; not USB.

Maybe you can find a USB to 35mm headphone adapter, and try that. I can't promise it would work, but is should be at least worth a try.